# How to increase the number of expand levels allowed for an OData request?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate (ASP.NET Core) project and OData implementation. Where and how do I increase the level of expands I can use in OData requests? I'm currently getting the following when requesting 3 levels of expands:

> "The request includes a $expand path which is too deep. The maximum allowed is 2.

I'd like to increase it to 3.

Regards
David

Comment: Its Asp.Net Core feature

Answer (score 1):

You can add `EnableQuery` attribute with `MaxExpansionDepth` option configured on your methods in `AbpODataEntityController<TEntity>`

For example,

```cs
public class PersonsController : AbpODataEntityController<Person>, ITransientDependency 
{
    public PersonsController(IRepository<Person> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10)]
    public override IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return base.Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the attribute as described to the Get method of the Odata controller but it hasn't made any difference, still issues ""The request includes a $expand path which is too deep. The maximum allowed is 2.". I there something else I need to set ?

Comment: I am also finding that this fix does not work for me.